# Dagger 2: How to inject Map<Class<? extends Foo>, Provider<? extends Foo>>

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

In Dagger 2, is it possible to inject a `Map<Class<? extends Foo>, Provider<? extends Foo>>`?

Suppose, I have a couple of classes that extends `Foo`

```java
class Bar extends Foo {
    @Inject Bar() {}
}

class Baz extends Foo {
    @Inject Baz() {}
}
```

and now I want to create a `FooFactory` by declaring

```java
class FooFactory {
    @Inject FooFactory(Map<Class<? extends Foo>, Provider<? extends Foo>> providers) {}
}
```

Can I do this in Dagger 2 with minimal configuration? I've read about [Multibinding](https://google.github.io/dagger//multibindings.html) but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Answering my own question in accordance to the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).</sub>

---

First, you have to get rid of the wildcard in `Provider<? extends Foo>`.

Second, you need to declare an annotation for the map key:

```java
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
public @interface FooKey {
    Class<? extends Foo> value();
}
```

Then, for each implementation of `Foo` you need to declare in your `Module`:

```java
@Binds @IntoMap @FooKey(Bar.class)
abstract Foo bindBar(Bar bar)
```

Comment: Did you mean `@FooKey(Bar.class)` instead of `@ViewModelKey` in the second part?

Comment: @DavidMedenjak yes, thanks you. I've edited the answer