# Binding Into Map With KClass Type

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to bind subclasses of `ViewModel` into a map by their `KClass` types:

```
@Module abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds @IntoMap @ViewModelKey(MyViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindsMyViewModel(viewModel: MyViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

}
```

But I am getting Dagger compiler error:

```
e: ~/Example/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/app/injection/AppComponent.java:5: error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
e: 

e: public abstract interface AppComponent {
e:                 ^
e:       java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is injected at
e:           com.example.app.ui.ViewModelFactory.<init>(creators)
e:       com.example.app.ui.ViewModelFactory is injected at
e:           com.example.app.injection.ViewModelModule.bindViewModelFactory(p0)
e:       android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
e:           com.example.app.ui.MyFragment.setViewModelFactory(p0)
e:       com.example.app.ui.MyFragment is injected at
e:           dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

The above `ViewModelModule` is included in my `AppModule`, which is a module in my `AppComponent`. So Dagger should be able to provide the `Map<KClass<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>` required by my `ViewModelFactory`, but I cannot figure out why it is crashing.

---

I also tried switching the `ViewModelKey` annotation class over to Java, taking a `Class` as a constructor parameter instead of a `KClass`. Then modified my `ViewModelFactory` to depend on a `Map<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>`, but the same error occurred.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

When using `KClass` in an annotation, it actually gets compiled to Java's `Class`. But the actual issue is the wildcard in `java.util.Map<kotlin.reflect.KClass<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,? extends javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>>` that the Kotlin compiler is generating.

Assuming that `@ViewModelKey` is defined as

```
@MapKey
annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)
```

You'll need to define your injection site as

```
Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
```

Using `@JvmSuppressWildcards` will prevent the compiler from generating wildcards.

I don't know why wildcards are not supported by the Dagger compiler. You can see a similar issue here: [Dagger 2: How to inject Map<Class<? extends Foo>, Provider<? extends Foo>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164395/dagger-2-how-to-inject-mapclass-extends-foo-provider-extends-foo/44165488#44165488)

Comment: Amazing. I would have never gotten to this, all the Google Android Architecture projects are in Java !

Comment: I would upvote 10 times if I could.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Does that mean that you cannot inject `KClass<T>`, only `Class<T>` into Kotlin code?

Comment: @andras You can, however neither of those are injected here.

Comment: @KirillRakhman You said `When using KClass in an annotation, it actually gets compiled to Java's Class`. I think that's true because I did a couple tests. Dagger2 always threw an error when I tried to inject `KClass`, independent whether the annotation's value was `KClass` (like in your `ViewModelKey` example) or just `Class`. In every linked example there is always a `Class` injected. I wish I could see the actual dependency graph in Dagger2 for debugging, but there is no way for that, not even when using `kapt` instead `annotationProcessor`. (TLDR: But how?)