# Why adding @Singleton annotation to ViewModelProvider.Factory implementation causes a compile error [Dagger/MissingBinding]?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I've been trying to use Dagger2 to inject a `ViewModelProvider.Factory` implementation as in this example: [GithubBrowserExample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/viewmodel/GithubViewModelFactory.kt) I copied the exact same class, however, when I try to build I get the following error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<? extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>,javax.inject.Provider<android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

I've spent 2 days trying to find a solution and everything was about wildcards and using `@JvmSuppressWildcards` annotation which I had already used in my class, I also tried to change `Map` for `MutableMap` in the constructor signature only to get the same frustrating error, until I accidentally removed `@Singleton` from:

```
@Singleton
class GithubViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        val creator = creators[modelClass] ?: creators.entries.firstOrNull {
            modelClass.isAssignableFrom(it.key)
        }?.value ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class $modelClass")
        try {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

and after that, my proyect compiled and that annoying error disappeared! what am I doing wrong?

Comment: should work fine check the versions for dependencies you have

Comment: I'm guessing that you added some scope (other than @Singleton) on your `@Multibinds` declaration and/or viewmodel bindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [David Medenjak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak) correctly pointed out, the problem was related to the scopes, it turned out that I was including `ViewModelModule` in my `MainActivityModule` and not in my `AppModule` and due to component/subcomponent structure `AppModule` didn't know how to provide the `GithubViewModelFactory` because the `@Provides` was inside a child subcomponent.